# How to replace only one column in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function like this but the problem is, it replaces the first column and when it replaces the next column, the previous column won't go back to it's original form.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as la

def CramersRule(A,b):
    for c in range (n):
        detA1 = la.det(A)
        A[:,c] = b.transpose()
        print A
        x = la.det(A)/detA1
        print ("X%d: ")%(c+1),x

n = input ("Enter size of matrix nxn: ")
coeff_matrix = input ("\nEnter coefficient matrix A: ")
vec_constants = input ("Enter vector of constants b: ")
A = np.array(coeff_matrix)
b = np.array(vec_constants)
print A

CramersRule(A, b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will put back the replaced column of `A`

```
def CramersRule(A,b):
    for c in range (n):
        detA1 = la.det(A)
        temp = np.array(A[:,c])
        A[:,c] = b.transpose()
        print A
        x = la.det(A)/detA1
        print ("X%d: ")%(c+1),x
        A[:,c]=temp.transpose()
```

`temp = np.array(A[:,c])` temporarily stores the replaced column of `A`. Interestingly without explicit `np.array()` `temp` will change as `A[:,c]` changes. `A[:,c]=temp.transpose()` reassigns the old column to `A`.